# Synchronization problem between main UI thread and AsyncTask

Tags: android

I've an inner class `FetchConvoinBackground` that `extends AsyncTask` and in `doInBackGround()` method I've called `retrieveConversations()`. The code snippet of `retrieveConversations()` method is;

```
private void retrieveConversations() {

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/");
    Cursor convoCursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{"thread_id","snippet"}, null,null,"date DESC");
    String convoID; //ID of the convo
    String snippet; // the heading SMS of the convo

    convoCursor.moveToFirst();
    for(int i=0;i<convoCursor.getCount();i++) {
        //try {
        //    Thread.sleep(200);
        //} catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //    e.printStackTrace();
        //}
        conversation = new Conversation();
        convoID = convoCursor.getString(convoCursor.getColumnIndex("thread_id"));
        snippet = convoCursor.getString(convoCursor.getColumnIndex("snippet"));
        String[] nameNumber = getConvoSenderNameNumber(convoID);
        if(nameNumber[1].equals("")){ //if nameNumber[1]=="", then the associated thread has no received message.
            convoCursor.moveToNext();
            continue;
        }
        //which has only two indeces; 0 for name, 1 for Number
        conversation.put(convoID, nameNumber[0], nameNumber[1], snippet); //getConvoSenderNameNumber() returns nameNumber array of strings
        Log.d("Async sender",""+conversation.sender);
        mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("main UI sender",""+conversation.sender);
                conversationList.add(conversation);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        convoCursor.moveToNext();
    }
    convoCursor.close();
}
```

With the current code layout if `retrieveConversations()` is called by `doInBackGround()` of `AsyncTask`, it has to run the code smoothly until `mainHandler.post()` method and then run the code in `mainHandler.post()'s run()` method and so it has to put the updated value of `conversation` in `conversationList`**(conversationList is an ArrayList of `Conversation` class)**. But unfortunately that's not the case. the value of conversation is written in the code before `mainHandler.post()` but in `mainHandler.post()` sometimes the value `null` is put in `conversationsList`, sometimes a previous value is put or sometimes the instance of `mainHandler.post()` is skipped.

When I use a `Thread.sleep(200)`*(below 200 the same problem as above occurs)*, the everything works fine but that costs me a lot of time. *How can the `mainHandler.post()` method be `wait()` until the `conversation` is written successfully and then after it is written, `wait()` until it is put successfully in `conversationsList?`*

Comment: So first off the reason you sometimes find `conversation` to be `null` is because you are probably assigning the `null` to it, so in your code check wherever you are setting it to null. Then you might want to create a local `Conversation` object. You are going to have to make it final to access in the `post` call.

Comment: Also I recommend to add the `Conversation` object to the list before the `post` call and simply call `notifyDataInserted()` in the `post` method instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()`.